SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission in Android 14 causes users to crash Experience
in my flutter application I am not using any of the alarms this when uploading to play console it give me the warning

Your app schedules exact alarms without checking whether the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM permission has been granted. This is causing your app to crash for users on Android 14 because the permission is no longer granted by default.

I have tested the whole project but don't get any such alarm. How to solve the issue?
pubspec.yaml
name: ******
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 4.0.0+16

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.0
  intl: ^0.18.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  mvc_pattern: ^7.4.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
  google_sign_in: ^6.1.5
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  geolocator: ^7.7.1
  google_place: ^0.4.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.9
  permission_handler: ^8.3.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  dio: ^5.3.3
  provider: ^6.0.0
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.2
  google_api_headers: ^1.3.0
  tuple: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.0
  numberpicker: ^2.1.1
  razorpay_flutter: ^1.2.7
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.8.3
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.2
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.3.4
  flutter_share: ^2.0.0
  get: ^4.6.5
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.1

  # rahul's
  mime: ^1.0.1
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
  path: ^1.8.0
  file_picker: ^5.3.3
  flutter_bloc: ^7.2.0
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  duration_picker: ^1.1.0+1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  flutter_tags: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.1
  country_state_city_picker: ^1.2.8
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.2
  envied: ^0.3.0+3
  pinput: ^2.3.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.8.0+1
  share_plus: ^4.5.3
  lecle_downloads_path_provider: ^0.0.1
  app_settings: ^4.2.0
  pdf: ^3.10.1
  printing: ^5.6.6
  open_file: ^3.3.2
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  build_runner: ^2.4.6
  envied_generator:
  flutter_pdfview: ^1.3.2
  logger: ^2.0.2+1
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.8.0
  dotted_border: ^2.1.0
  webview_flutter_android: ^2.10.4
  device_preview: ^1.1.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.9
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.9.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/app_logo/
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/icons/order/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/json/

  fonts:
    - family: MontserratMedium
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf
    - family: MontserratSemiBold
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf

manifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="*******">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>


<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="BitesVilla">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/logo" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true" />    
    
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="${GMP_KEY}" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
      


        <!-- Deep linking -->
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="bitesvilla.page.link" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="bitesvilla.page.link" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <meta-data         
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"                 
        android:value="high_importance_channel" />
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"

        android:value="2" />

    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver"/>
    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>


<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
    <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent>
</queries>
</manifest>



its just a warning, if you are not seeing actual crashes in the console then you are fine. 2. you are probably using a library that is using alarms, you should probably check the libraries that you are using


You need to check the merged manifest - some library you're using is requesting that permission if you're not.

@dominicoder how to check merged manifest??? Can you tell me steps to produce merged manifest ????

I provided a link that gives you all the information you need already ...

You take the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM alert because you use flutter_local_notifications (^9.8.0+1). If you use version 16 or higher of flutter_local_notifications package, you will get rid of this warning.

You should use a package that use this permission.
you'll have to identifiy this package first. Then, check if there is an update for that package and see if this resolve the issue.
If the package is unmaintained try to see if another package doing the same exists an replace it.
If nothing of this solve the problem, you can fork the pacake on github, delete the SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM if not needed by the package. If needed, please read Android documentaiton about this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/schedule-exact-alarms?hl=fr
